# Restrict Mouse Move only on a Specified Area

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void MoveCursor()
{
   // Set the Current cursor, move the cursor's Position,
   // and set its clipping rectangle to the form. 

   this.Cursor = new Cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle);
   Cursor.Position = new Point(Cursor.Position.X - 50, Cursor.Position.Y - 50);
   Cursor.Clip = new Rectangle(this.Location, this.Size);
}
```

I am using the above code to Restrict the movement but still I am able to move the mouse outside the form?

Can I restrict the mouse movement to a specified area in the form? Please advise...

Comment: That code only works when the mouse is captured by a control. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.capture(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Updated answer:

`ClipCursor` is the API function you require.  You will need to supply screen-based coordinates.

```
BOOL WINAPI ClipCursor(RECT *lpRect);
```

take a look at [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648383(VS.85).aspx)  for the Win32 API code, and [this one](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.clipcursor) for pinvoke from C#.

<s>There is pair of Win32 API functions called [SetCapture/ReleaseCapture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646262(v=vs.85).aspx) that will restrict the mouse to a certain window bounds.</s>

You will need to use PInvoke to use them, but this will work.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr SetCapture(long hWnd);

SetCapture(Control.Handle);
```

One thing to bear in mind, is that if used incorrectly, it's possible that the user will not be able to click the [X] to shut down your application because the mouse will not be able to get to the title bar.

Comment: [SetCapture](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.setcapture) and [ReleaseCapture](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.releasecapture) pInvoke signatures.

Comment: What about the [Control.Capture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.capture(v=vs.110).aspx) property? That doesn't seem to require P/Invoke.

Comment: `Control.Capture` Only garuantess that the control _receives_ mouse input. As noted, though:

> Also, even if the foreground window has captured the mouse, the user can still click another window, bringing it to the foreground.

Comment: Thanks Neil, I have tried your solution but I am able to move the mouse around, only there is a restriction on mouse clicking.

Comment: Sorry @ChikkuJacob my answer is incorrect.  It will not restrict the mouse to a certain window.  I'm sure I've done this in the past, so will keep researching.

Comment: Ah, it's ClipCursor.  Take a look at this page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648383(VS.85).aspx and this is the pinvoke: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.clipcursor

Comment: @Neil Thanks mate... lets try, i will post the answer if i manage to find too