# Set the maximum mouse positions globally, not just on the wpf window

Tags: c#, wpf

I am making a menu that would open over other applications. The menu is very simple. And it looks like this:

[image]

Eventually it will look like pings in game league of legends:

[image]

Window with 4 buttons appears in at the current mouse position and is visible as long as the bound button is pressed. By moving the mouse on the appropriate button, we make a selection.

I would like the mouse to not go out of the buttons while holding the button. I tried with the MouseMove and MouseLeave events. But when you move the mouse faster, it unfortunately manages to leave the button fields.I am looking for some optimal solution, or for example to reduce the speed of the mouse, which makes it difficult to leave the field and, if you catch the MouseLeave event, return the mouse to middle.

But is there any way to just limit the maximums of X and Y.

I would like to add that the application could be used while playing games, so such a teleportation of the mouse could be recognized as a cheat.

Windows is transparent.

```
WindowStyle="None" KeyUp="Window_KeyUp"
<Window.Background>
    <SolidColorBrush Opacity="0" Color="White"/>
</Window.Background>
```

My current code:

```
    int lastX = 140;
    int lastY = 140;
    private void Window_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var a = e.GetPosition(MiniMenuWindow);
        int newX = (int)a.X;
        int newY = (int)a.Y;
        if (a.X < 70)
            newX = 70;
        if (a.X > 210)
            newX = 210;
        if (a.Y < 70)
            newY = 70;
        if (a.Y > 210)
            newY = 210;
        if(newX<140)
            lastX = 100;
        else
            lastX = 180;
        if (newY < 140)
            lastY = 100;
        else
            lastY = 180;

        if (newX != (int)a.X || newY != (int)a.Y)
            NativeMethods.SetCursorPos((int)MiniMenuWindow.Left + newX, (int)MiniMenuWindow.Top + newY);
        
    }

    private void MiniMenuWindow_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        NativeMethods.SetCursorPos((int)MiniMenuWindow.Left + lastX, (int)MiniMenuWindow.Top + lastY);
    }
```

Comment: Have you captured the mouse?  Capturing means your window gets all mouse messages, even if they are outside your window.

Comment: Also, I possibly answered your question 3 years ago :-)  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44569522/restrict-mouse-move-only-on-a-specified-area (not sure if this will work on WPF)

Comment: @Neil no actually only from wpf Window. Thanks for link I will test that.

Comment: Just so we're in the same page, the League of Legends ping system does **not** capture your cursor.

Comment: @Blindy So should I handle this menu differently?

Comment: Up to you, I'm just saying the comparison you gave doesn't follow your requirements, besides being a rotary menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using ClipCursor, takes a rectangle as param and confines the mouse in the rectangle:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-clipcursor